# How do I add class to an admin comment?

Tags: comments

When I customize the wp_list_comments() output, how do I add a class to the admin comments?

Relevant code:

```
<?php wp_list_comments( array( 'style' => 'ol', 'callback' => 'custom_list_comments' ) ); ?>
```

---

```
<?php
if( ! function_exists( 'custom_list_comments' ) ):
function custom_list_comments( $comment, $args, $depth ) {
?>
<li id="comment-<?php comment_ID() ?>">
    <?php echo get_avatar( $comment, 48 ); ?>
    <?php comment_text(); ?>
    <span><?php echo get_comment_author() ?></span>
    <time><?php comment_time(); ?></time>
    <?php comment_reply_link( array_merge( $args, array( 'depth' => $depth, 'max_depth' => $args['max_depth'] ) ) ); ?>
    <?php edit_comment_link(); ?>
<?php
}
endif;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to add some custom class to a `li` tag if the comment was posted by an administrator is to replace line

`<li id="comment-<?php comment_ID() ?>">`

with

`<li <?php comment_class(); ?> id="comment-<?php comment_ID() ?>">`

This will add support for the default WP comments classes to your comments callback.

Once you do that add in your theme functions.php file the code below it will add class "posted-by-admin" to the `li` tag classes if the comment author is an administrator.

```
add_filter( "comment_class", function( $classes, $class, $comment_id, $comment ) {
    if( $comment->user_id > 0 && $user = get_userdata( $comment->user_id ) && user_can( $comment->user_id, "administrator" ) ) {
        $classes[] = "posted-by-admin";
    }
    return $classes; 
}, 10, 4 );
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to work. Does `<span><?php echo get_comment_author() ?></span>` need to be modified?

Comment: Where exactly do you want to add an additional class? to the span around the comment author?

Comment: Sorry, it is my problem, it is effective, thank for your answer!